# PDO with table prefix

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the follow Model class, which all my models extends.

```
class Model {
    [...]
    protected static $_query; // Query preparated

    public function prepare($query = null) {
        [...] // Connect to PDO, bla bla bla

        self::$_query = self::$link->prepare($query);
    }

    [...]

}

class Login extends Model {
    public function getUser($username = null) {
        self::prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1');
        self::bindValue('username', $username);

        return self::fetch();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I need to insert prefix to my mysql, to avoid table conflicts, but don't want to edit all my querys.

```
clientone_tablename
clienttwo_tablename
clientthree_tablename
```

How I can do this, parse and insert table prefix when prepare the query?

I have not tried nothing because what I know is, extend my custom PDO to PHP PDO class, which is not much now..

I have seen this:  [PDO - Working with table prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472250/pdo-working-with-table-prefixes). But don't worked propertly..

Thanks!

Comment: do you really need a client name for each table? couldn't you generate a random set of digits and append that to say "tbl_client" so that it would become like "tbl_client4455" and then store that table name in your `clients` table so you know which table is for which client?

Comment: @Ozzy So ugly this way..

Comment: I wonder what you make of parsing SQL then ?? But instead of the numbers you could just add their names (i.e. `SELECT name FROM clients WHERE id=?`) then append that to the table name. Besides whats ugly about it when no one is supposed to be able to see it (private info about your clients?). It should only be accessed through your program so the name is sort of hidden anyway.

Comment: @Ozzy I have tables like `users`, `news`, `pages`, `files`. I want to haveone of each (and others) table for each client. Because is one mysql with multiple client projects. So, this is not the best way.

Comment: I will post you an answer (example) to show you what I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've assume you have only 1 MySQL database (minimum package on your webhost) and need to store a copy of a system for each of your clients.

What I was suggesting, is that you create a separate set of tables as you already are (for each client), but the name wont matter because you have a look-up of the table names in your clients table.

Heres my example for you: The clients table should store the table names of their own tables
(e.g. users_tbl = clientone_users for client id:1) So that later on you can just query the clients table and get his/her table names, then use that result to query on his/her user, news, pages, and files tables.

```
# SQL: new table structure
-- store the names of the clients tables here
CREATE TABLE clients(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    name VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(250),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    pass BLOB,
    /* table names*/
    users_tbl VARCHAR(70),
    news_tbl VARCHAR(70),
    pages_tbl VARCHAR(70),
    files_tbl VARCHAR(70)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

# PHP: Some definitions for the table structure
$tbl_names = array("_users","_news","_pages","_files");
$tbl_fields = array();
$tbl_fields[0] = array("id INT","users_col1 VARCHAR(10)","users_col2 VARCHAR(20)");
$tbl_fields[1] = array("id INT","news_col1 DATE",...);
$tbl_fields[2] = array(...);
$tbl_fields[3] = array(...);
// refers to YOUR clients table field names (see above)
$clients_fields = array("users_tbl", "news_tbl", "pages_tbl", "files_tbl");

# PHP: Create a user and create the users database
function createUser($name, $address, $email, $pass, $salt) {
    global $db, $tbl_names, $tbl_fields;
    $success = false;
    if ($db->beginTransaction()) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO clients(name, address, email, pass)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?));"
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($name, $address, $email, $pass, $salt));
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1) { # if rowCount() doesn't work
            # get the client ID        # there are alternative ways
            $client_id = $db->lastInsertId();
            for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($tbl_names); $i++) {
                $client_tbl_name = $name . $tbl_names[$i];
                $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $client_tbl_name . "("
                           . implode(',', $tbl_fields[$i]) . ");";
                if (!$db->query($sql)) {
                    $db->rollBack();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $sql = "UPDATE clients SET ".clients_fields[$i]."=? "
                                       ."WHERE id=?;";
                    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                    if (!$query->execute(
                            array($client_tbl_name, (int)$client_id)
                                         )) {
                        $db->rollBack();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            $db->commit();
            $success = true;
        }
        if (!$success) $db->rollBack();
    }
    return $success;
}

# PHP: Get the Client's table names
function getClientsTableNames($client_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT (users_tbl, news_tbl, pages_tbl, files_tbl)
              FROM clients WHERE id=?;";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    if ($query->execute(array((int)$client_id)))
        return $query->fetchAll();
    else
        return null;
}

# PHP: Use the table name to query it
function getClientsTable($client_id, $table_no) {
    $table_names = getClientsTableNames($client_id);
    if ($table_names != null && isset($table_names[$table_no])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_names[$table_no].";";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        if ($query->execute(array((int)$client_id)))
            return $query->fetchAll();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think I will lose some performance, but basically, it is like `self::prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . self::getPrefix([$dbname if multiple DB, or null for current DB]) . 'usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1');`.. (static member could be `$this->getPrefix()`, or `$db->getPrefix()`, etc)

Comment: I just used the normal PDO, PDOStatement code, but if you see what I'm saying you can just alter the code to work with your database abstraction layer.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm talking: with this way, I need to have a method/function to insert the prefix. For this, I can store the prefix in config.php and get with `$db->getPrefix()` for instance, which is the easiest way.. With this approach, what about `self::prepare('SELECT * FROM #__usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1');`, and inside my Model `prepare()` replace `#__` to config.php defined table prefix.

Comment: it would be easier to inclue the file that defines the prefix `require_once('table_settings.php');`, define the prefix as global in the function so that you have access to it `getUser { global $prefix; ... }`, then do it like this: `self::prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$prefix.'usuarios WHERE usuario = :username');` but I think whichever way will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me to think this way. =)

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite your queries to use a table prefix found in a variable somewhere.  Parsing all your queries for tablenames is more trouble than it is worth. (Do you really want to write an SQL parser?)

Comment: I think is more easy to parse.. I don't like to `self::prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . self::getPrefix() . 'usuarios WHERE usuario = :username LIMIT 1');`.. If I have a compelx query, this is like a non clean way to do this..

Comment: I'm not sure how you could think that writing an sql parser is easier than string interpolation. (Also, stop using static members! What if you want to use two different prefixes in the same application?)

Comment: Whit our without static members, I need to get prefix from database.. `self::getPrefix('db1')` and `self::getPrefix('db2')`.